# Minimum cost to make connect all nodes in one partition of a weighted undirected bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, bipartite

Given a weighted undirected bipartite graph between partition A and B, I'm trying to find the minimum cost to connect all nodes in partition A.

It seems like I need to first find a Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) of the whole graph and then exclude edges that are unnecessary (since I don't need to connect nodes in partition B). What I thought was to remove nodes in partition B with degree of 1 (only connected to 1 node in partition A) from the MST, but this method gave sub-optimal in some cases.

Hope somebody can help me on this.

Input format:

- 1st line is N and M - size of partition A and B (1 < N, M < 1000)
- Next is the cost matrix of size N x M. The value at row i and column j would be the cost to connect A[i] to B[j]

Output format:

- The minimal cost to connect all nodes in A

Sample input:

```
3 4
1 2 3 7
1 3 1 2
3 4 1 7
```

Sample output:

```
4
```

Explanation:

- Connect A[1] to B[1], A[2] to B[1], A[2] to B[3], and A[3] to B[3].This will connect all three nodes in A with the minimal cost of 4 in total.

Comment: Input/Output examples would help.

Comment: [Edited] I added input/output examples

Comment: That helped, I think I have a solution. Will be posting it in sometime

Answer (score 0):

Partitions: `A` and `B`

Nodes:      `m` and `n` (m,n < 1000)

We are trying to connect all nodes in `A`

**Step 1:** Create an exhaustive list of pairs of A-nodes, with min cost required to connect them. This will be (max) `mC2 = m * (m-1) / 2` elements long list. For the example in the post, this will look like:

```
[(A1,A2,2), (A1,A3,4), (A2,A3,2)]
```

This is essentially a new graph with nodes only from A and respective edge weights. The easiest way to accomplish creating this is `O(m^2 * n)`

**Step 2:** This becomes your weighted graph for which you can apply MST logic to get to your final answer which will be `O(m^2)` solution (since number of edges `~m^2` >> number of nodes `=m`)

Comment: This is actually not correct, because you overcount the edge. For example, if the optimal way is to connect A1 to B1, A2 to B1 and A3 to B1. When you create a new graph like what you say, you will have edge A1-A2 (through B1) and edge A2-A3 (also through B1). If you just sum the weights together in this new graph, you added the cost A2-B1 twice!

Comment: Oh, great point. Now that you mention it, I feel kinda silly for missing such a basic case. However, do you think if we add a 4th param (connecting B-node) and use that to calculate weight, would that work?

Comment: I need to brush myself up and read Kruskal's again and maybe come up with a solution